# How to pass options object to postcss 8 plugin using JS API?

Tags: postcss

I wrote an postcss 8 plugin and would like to forward an options object to be used.
The script to run postcss is from the docs [https://github.com/postcss/postcss#js-api]

```
const postcss = require('postcss')
const resizer = require('../index.js')
const fs = require('fs')

let fileSrc = 'css/src2.css';
let fileDst = 'css/dest.css';

fs.readFile(fileSrc, (err, css) => {

  postcss([resizer])
    .process(css, { from: fileSrc, to: fileDst}, { factor: 0.75 })
    .then(result => {
      fs.writeFile(fileDst, result.css, () => true)
      if (result.map) {
        fs.writeFile(fileDst + '.map', result.map.toString(), () => true)
      }
    })
})
```

I tried to use the third argument slot of the .process() method as in the code [postcss.js] but the plugin dones not receive this data

```
creator.process = function (css, processOpts, pluginOpts) {
```

postcss version: 8.2.8

Answer (score 0):

Try adding the plugin options in the plugins array instead, like:

```
postcss([ resizer({ factor: 0.75 }) ])
```